# Moving an input file into another folder whenever it encounters specific result

Tags: perl

I have written a script in perl that reads each file in current directory and calculates distances between protein and ligand atom. Whenever it encounters condition that the result is `<=5` it should break the loop (`last`) and move this file into another directory (`mp`) that was previously made. For some reason I have a problem with this script; it calcluates the distances correctly but does not move these files into another folder. It does not give me any error tough. I am trying to figure out what  seems to be a problem.

This is the script that I have been using:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Glob;

mkdir "mp";
my $txt;

for my $txt ( glob '*.txt' ) 
{

    open my $fh, '<', $txt;
    my $out_fh;

    my (@refer, @points);
    my $part = 0;
    my $dist;

    while (my $line = <$fh>) 
    { 
        chomp($line);

        $part++ if ($line =~ /^HETATM/);

        my @array = (substr($line, 30, 8),substr($line,38,8),substr($line,46,8));
        #print "@array\n";

        if ($part == 0) 
        {
            push @refer, [ @array ]; 
        } 

        elsif ($part)
        {
            push @points, [ @array ]; 
        }

        my $atom;

        foreach my $ref(@refer) 
        {
            my ($x1, $y1, $z1) = @{$ref};
            foreach my $atom(@points) 
            {
               my ($x, $y, $z) = @{$atom};
               my $dist = sqrt( ($x-$x1)**2 + ($y-$y1)**2 + ($z-$z1)**2 );
               if ($dist <= 5)
               {
                    print "Distance for calculation between $ref and                                 $atom is $dist\n";
                    last;
                    system ("mv $fh mp");
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

The content of my input file looks like this:

```
ATOM   1593 HD21 LEU D  46      11.528  -8.800   5.301  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM   1594 HD22 LEU D  46      12.997  -9.452   4.535  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM   1595 HD23 LEU D  46      11.722  -8.718   3.534  1.00  0.00           H  
HETATM 1597  N1  308 A   1       0.339   6.314  -9.091  1.00  0.00           N  
HETATM 1598  C10 308 A   1      -0.195   5.226  -8.241  1.00  0.00           C
```

The result that script gives me in terminal looks like this:

```
Distance for calculation between ARRAY(0x1c61fa8) and ARRAY(0x1c6f950) is 4.98553437456809
Distance for calculation between ARRAY(0x1c62098) and ARRAY(0x1c6ffe0) is 4.98962253081333
```

But it does not move the files.

Comment: Change `system ("mv $fh mp");`  to  `system ("mv $fh mp") or die "Error: $!";` to see if you get any error

Comment: @Jens `and die` as [system](http://p3rl.org/system) returns the exit status. It would be better to use [rename](http://p3rl.org/rename).

Comment: are you on Linux or Windows?
if you are on Windows, the command is `move` not `mv`

Comment: Oh I see, I don't get any error. I guess it was something in this line although it didn't gave me any error before as well. How can I close each file so that it can move? Thanks!

Comment: Linux, linux. I previously used this command that why I was confused.

Comment: I think the file is moved before being closed.

Comment: @saudic: Why do you think that? (Please give evidence.) And what is the solution? (Please offer a correction.)

Comment: milan Do you work with @Djordje ?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48394267/renaming-a-file-if-it-fulfills-two-conditions/48395306?noredirect=1#comment83866522_48395306

Comment: @dlamblim I have no idea who djordje is