# Renaming a file if it fulfills two conditions

Tags: perl

I am reading many `pdb` files from current directory, in each of the file I am concentrating on specific lines and I am putting two conditions and if these conditions are fulfiled then I am trying to rename the file by adding certain elements from the line to its existing filename. My lines that I am operating with look like this:

```
HET     CA  A 800       1                                                       
HET    SO4  A 901       5                                                       
HET    SO4  A 902       5                                                       
HET    SO4  A 903       5                                                       
HET    RAM  A 509      11                                                       
HET    GTR  A 510      12                                                       
HET    RAM  A 511      15                                                       
HET    GTR  A 512      12                                                       
HET    RAM  A 513      15                                                       
HET    GTR  A 514      12                                                       
HETNAM      CA CALCIUM ION                                                      
HETNAM     SO4 SULFATE ION                                                      
HETNAM     RAM ALPHA-L-RHAMNOSE                                                 
HETNAM     GTR BETA-D-GALACTOPYRANURONIC ACID                                   
HETSYN     GTR GALACTURONIC ACID                                                
FORMUL   2   CA    CA 2+                                                        
FORMUL   3  SO4    3(O4 S 2-)                                                   
FORMUL   6  RAM    3(C6 H12 O5 N5)                                                 
FORMUL   6  GTR    3(C6 H10 O7)                                                 
FORMUL   7  HOH   *362(H2 O)
```

- I am reading lines that start with `HET`  and `FORMUL`.
- From `HET` lines I am reading last column or 4th element. From `FORMUL` lines I am reading last column.
- If the number from `HET` lines is `>= 6` and if under `FORMUL` there is `C >= 2` `&&` `sum of O C N` is `>= 6` then I want to grep the 3rd element under `FORMUL` line and to put it into filename.

So for example, from this input only `RAM` fulfills both conditions because it has `15` under `HET` and `sum of C O N` is `=>6` in `FORMUL`, so I am expecting to grep `RAM` and to add it into filename that has been processed. So something like this : `filename_RAM` if there are more elements that fulfill both conditions then more elements will be added to the `filename`

I have written the script that looks like this:

```
#! usr/bin/env perl

use autodie;
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Glob;

my $pdbs;
my $fh;
my @fh;
my @data;
my $c;
my @lines;
my $lines;
my $file_sz;
my $line;
my @colums;
my $colums;
my @het;
my $het;
my $cols;
my @cols;
my %letters;
my @hetnam;
my $hetnam;

foreach my $pdbs (glob '*pdb') #Reading each pdb file from the current directory
{
    printf "%s\n", $pdbs;
    open my $fh, "<" ,$pdbs;  #Read each pdb file into a filehandle
    #print "$fh\n";
    @lines= <$fh>;            #Putting content of each file into an array
    $file_sz = scalar @lines;
    #print "$file_sz\n";
    #print "@lines\n";

    for ($c=0; $c<=$#lines; $c++) #Reading each line
    {
        chomp ($lines[$c]);
        if ($lines[$c] =~ m/^HET /) #If line starts with HET 
        {   
            my @colums = split ' ', $lines[$c];
            # print join "\t", $colums [4];
            print "$colums[4]\n";       #Printing only a fifth column (4th element)
            push @hetnam, $colums[1];
        }

        if ($lines[$c] =~ m/^FORMUL /) #If line starts with FORMUL
        {   
            my @cols = split /\s+/, $lines[$c], 4;
            next unless $cols[0] eq 'FORMUL';   
            my %letters = $cols[-1] =~ m/([A-Z])(\d+)/g;
            $letters{$lines[$c]} = 0 for (qw[C O N]);
            next if $letters{C} <= 2
              and $letters{C} + $letters{O} + $letters{N} <= 6;
            #print "@cols\n";
        }

        if ($colums[4]=>6 && $letters{C} <= 2 && $letters{C} + $letters{O} + $letters{N} => 6) #line 61
        {
        system ("mv $pdbs $pdbs/_$hetnam");
        }
    }
}
```

The error that I am encountering is :

```
mv: accessing `4YE1.pdb/_': Not a directory
Use of uninitialized value $letters{"C"} in numeric le (<=) at script1 line 61, <$_[...]> line 5708.
Use of uninitialized value in addition (+) at script1 line 61, <$_[...]> line 5708.
```

Comment: Your script looks an order of magnitude too complex. It's not clear how the FORMUL calculation works but your specification looks like it could be written in 10 or so lines of Awk or Perl.

Comment: Also, note that `=>` and `>=` are two totally different operators in Perl

Comment: @tripleee Thanks. I is surely something wrong with assigning `%letters` because when I try to print `"@cols\n"` it is printing some formulas that are not fulfilling these conditions. I am not sure which approach should I take to change it..

Comment: Does `3(C6 H12 O5 N5)` calculate as 3*6 for C, 3*12 for H, 3*5 for O, 3*5 for N or what do the parentheses designate?

Comment: What if more than one entry in the file fulfills your conditions?

Comment: @triplee No, it should search and calculate only these numbers that are inside the brackets since `C, O & N` can only be found inside the brackets. For some formulas there are no brackets at all. if more then one entry under `^FORMUL ` and `^HET ` lines fulfills both conditions then it should add it to the filename that will be renamed. So the number of entries that fulfills both conditions that number of entries should be put in to the filename.

Comment: @djordje: Please stop editing your question to incorporate ideas from comments and answers. I have rolled back your edits so that people can see what they're answering.

Comment: @Borodin: I see, won't do it anymore! Thanks

Comment: @djordie Do you work with @Milan? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48283290/moving-an-input-file-into-another-folder-whenever-it-encounters-specific-result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code didn't attempt to implement crucial parts of the logic you describe, and had various small logic bugs in other places.  Here is an attempt at refactoring this into reasonably idiomatic Perl while keeping as much of your original as possible.

I have left out the actual renaming functionality, and left in some debugging prints to help you see how you might try to help yourself see what your program is doing while you are developing it.

```
#! usr/bin/env perl

use autodie;
use warnings;
use strict;

foreach my $pdb (<*pdb>)
{
    printf "# %s\n", $pdb;
    open my $fh, "<" ,$pdb;
    my %hets;
    my @suf;
    # Don't slurp the entire file. Just read a line at a time.
    for my $line (<$fh>)
    {
        chomp ($line);
        if ($line =~ m/^HET /)
        {   
            my @columns = split ' ', $line;
            ####print "$columns[4] < 6? ", ($columns[4] < 6 ? "yes" : "no"), "\n";
            next if $columns[4] < 6;
            # We have a HIT, er, HET -- remember it
            $hets{$columns[1]} = $columns[4];
            ####print "$columns[1] added to hets\n";
        }
        elsif ($line =~ m/^FORMUL /)
        {
            my @cols = split /\s+/, $line, 4;
            # If this is not in $hets, skip it
            ####print "$cols[2] in %hets? ", ($hets{$cols[2]} ? "yes" : "no"), "\n";
            next unless $hets{$cols[2]};
            ####print "\$cols[-1] is $cols[-1]\n";
            # Initialize these to zero _before_ extracting actual counts
            my %letters = (C=>0, O=>0, N=>0);
            while ($cols[-1] =~ m/([CON])(\d+)/g)
            {
                $letters{$1} = $2;
                ####print "\$letters{$1} = '$2'\n"
            }
            my $con = $letters{"C"} + $letters{"O"} + $letters{"N"};
            # Bug fix: next condition was wrong
            # ("next if this OR that" is equivalent to "don't next if this AND that")
            if ($letters{"C"}>2 && $con >= 6)
            {
                push @suf, $cols[2]
            }
        }
    }
    if (@suf)
    {
        print "rename $pdb, ", join("_", $pdb, @suf), "\n";
    }
    # my %hets and my @suf go out of scope here --
    # helps you find bugs and make sure you don't process old results
    # from a previous file
}
```

Declaring *all* your variabes as effectively global with `my` completely nullifies the reason to use `my` in the first place. The variable should be declared at the scope where you actually use it, and then forgotten when it goes out of scope. This is hard for beginners, but helps you down the line because you cannot stumble over your own feet by using the same variable for different things in different places, or operate on an old value from a previous iteration of the same loop (the value will be `undef` from the `my` declaration until you actually give it a value). And of course, declaring globals with `my` and then *redeclaring* them with `my` again in an enclosed scope is not only completely pointless, but also surely utterly confusing.

Apart from actually implementing many of the conditions you had in your requirements but not in your code, the major change here is collecting the matching suffixes while processing the lines in a file, then only attempting to rename it once we have processed the entire file.

#### Update by @Borodin

I have altered the code, hoping to explain my ideas in the comments. The semantics are identical: this is no refactoring, and I have no idea whether the logic is correct.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

for my $pdb ( glob '*pdb' ) {

    printf "# %s\n", $pdb;

    open my $fh, "<", $pdb;

    my %hets;
    my @suf;

    for my $line ( <$fh> ) {

        chomp( $line );

        if ( $line =~ m/^HET / ) {
            my @columns = split ' ', $line;
            next if $columns[4] < 6;

            $hets{ $columns[1] } = $columns[4];
        }
        elsif ( $line =~ m/^FORMUL / ) {

            my @cols = split /\s+/, $line, 4;

            next unless $hets{ $cols[2] };

            my %letters = ( C => 0, O => 0, N => 0 );

            while ( $cols[-1] =~ m/([CON])(\d+)/g ) {
                $letters{$1} = $2;
            }

            my $con = $letters{"C"} + $letters{"O"} + $letters{"N"};

            if ( $letters{"C"} > 2 && $con >= 6 ) {
                push @suf, $cols[2];
            }
        }
    }

    if ( @suf ) {
        print "rename $pdb, ", join( "_", $pdb, @suf ), "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Extracting the individual terms into a hash so that we can then sum them is kind of pointless; just add to the sum in the `while` loop and see where you land. You still have to add a check for the `C` value but this should be easy, and can also go inside the `while` loop.

Comment: 20 lines of Perl if you exclude comments, declarations, and lone braces. Oh and the two adjacent lines of `my` can be merged to a single line for compactness.

Comment: Both the answers I have posted assume that all the `HET` lines go before any `FORMUL` lines. If that is not the case, the logic will need an overhaul.

Comment: A simplification which is also a usability improvement would be to process files named as command-line arguments, instead of hard-coding a pattern, so you can run this on a single file or a number of files which might not be in the current directory and/or might not have a name which matches the glob `*pdb`.

Comment: With your experience of this site I would expect a better presentation of your solution. Please format your code following [`perldoc perlstyle`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html) so that it is less opaque.

Comment: I basically copy/pasted the OP's code and tweaked it. If you don't like having the opening curly on a line of its own, more power to you, but downvoting because of that seems a bit harsh. I spent a fair amount of time on second-guessing the OP's intentions and implementing the parts which were missing so I'd rather not need to delete this just because of stylistic quibs.

Comment: *"If you don't like having the opening curly on a line of its own, more power to you"* That is far from being the primary problem; why do all your `print` statements start on the left margin? *"I spent a fair amount of time on second-guessing the OP's intentions"* So you wasted your time. One of the main reasons for comments is to discover "the OP's intentions".

Comment: Please tag your comments with e.g. `@Borodin` if you want me to be notified of your messages.

Comment: @Borodin The debug prints are flush left so they are easy to remove before saving for production. Should I add a remark explaining this?

Comment: Of course you should. Or more preferably they shouldn't be there at all.

Comment: @Borodin Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163794/discussion-between-tripleee-and-borodin).

Comment: No, thank you. Writing poorly-formatted code and justifying it by claiming that it is full of debug code is a non-starter.

Comment: @Borodin I commented out the debug prints, any other feedback of yours I should incorporate still?

Comment: I think that is the worst possible choice. But you misunderstand me: you may publish whatever code *you think is best* while I may make *whatever comments* I think are appropriate. I may also apply whatever down-votes I think are appropriate without having to explain myself, but I have not down-voted this answer of yours.

Comment: @Borodin No issue with that, just saw your comments and a fresh downvote at around the same time -- sorry for jumping to a hasty conclusion. I grappled with this but felt the OP would be helped with a rewrite showing them how to do things properly, but if you think this isn't "properly" I want to fix it; however, it's been a long time since I wrote Perl for production.

Comment: What is "proper" can only ever be one individual's idea. That idea may be endorsed by many others and so become an adopted standard, but unless some of us break from it there will never be any advancements. My opinion is that "debug prints" don't belong in any demonstration of a solution, but I am no oracle. If the answer has no inherent output then I will often `use Data::Dump` and `dd \%result` at the end of the code and explain myself in the lead narrative, but debug code only ever means anything to the person who wrote it and I think you should avoid it altogether.

Comment: @Borodin Uff, Your code seems to work very fine after double checking it and apart from its accuracy it really looks very simple and readable. I think I have learned some new things from this code. Thanks.

Comment: Having spaces inside parentheses (and curlies) probably helps if you only have a very primitive text editor, but seems to deviate from the examples in the perlstyle document, and strikes me as *really* ugly.

Comment: @Borodin How can I alter it to directly rename original `pdb (input) files` and not to have it printed in terminal?

Comment: The `system` call you originally had will nominally work, though as already outlined in Borodin's answer, there are Perl-native alternatives to explore, too. As long as you don't put back the misplaced slash which threw off everyone, it's dead simple.

Comment: @Borodin When I try to run Your code on a larger dataset `(91 k)`  is gives me an error `use of uninitialized value $ columns [4] in numeric lt (<) at script.pl line 22`. Should I change it to `@ columns [4]` to assess the elements? And when I try to run it on whole sample. it should print `~91k` of lines and it prints `~60k`. You have some idea what can be the reason of printing less lines?

Comment: It means one of your files has malformed lines which don't contain five columns.

Comment: @triplee Oh no, cus when I read the manual of this file it all contain 5 columns in this line..it actually means that some files doesn not fulfil both conditions which is fine. I am just wondering does this warning can make impact on the result? And how should I fix it if it does?

Comment: If the error message contradicts the documentation, I would trust the error message. If you can figure out how to fix the malformed data, do that; otherwise, I suppose you will have to discard it.

Comment: You have tagged this [tag:perl] so people who respond here are likely to know how to fix Perl problems, not so much proper procedures for safety and validity in biochemical research.

Answer (score 2):

- ``` mv: accessing ``4YE1.pdb/_': Not a directory ```

  The `system` call is trying to move (and rename, which it never gets round to) the file `4YE1.pdb` under a folder of the same name, which it cannot find . If you intend to create a folder with the same name as the file (which I would highly discourage), you need to create it first with `mkdir` (or an equivalent).
- `Use of uninitialized value $letters{"C"} in numeric le (<=) at script1 line 61, <$_[...]> line 5708`

  Changes/assignments made to `%letters` only exists in the scope of the `if` block as it was localized with `my`. To make it available to both `if` blocks, remove the `my`.

  So instead of:

  ```
  my %letters;
  if ( ... ) { my %letters = ... }
  if ( ... ) { next if $letters{C} ... }
  ```

  Write it as:

  ```
  my %letters;
  if ( ... ) { %letters = ... }
  if ( ... ) { next if $letters{C} ... }
  ```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I tried to add module `File::Copy` and to use `rename`. I removed `my` from the loop as You showed but it seems something else is wrong inside the loop when assigning `%letters` and I'm not sure how to change it. Now it gives me an errors: `Useless use of array element in void context at script1 line 67.
Useless use of addition (+) in void context at script1 line 67.` and `Use of uninitialized value $letters{"C"} in numeric gt (>) at script1 line 61, <$_[...]> line 38514.`. I am not sure how it is uninitialized when it should be `0` and there is no `array` in `line 67`.

Comment: Your comment seems out of place. If the slash in `$pdbs/_$hetnam` is a typo, the simple fix is to remove the typo.

Comment: @tripleee are you referring to something I wrote in the answer or the OP's comment to my answer?

Comment: That's in reference to the OP's comment, though maybe you want to incorporate this into your first bullet point, too.

Comment: @tripleee I just wanted to include `_` in the filename so that it can be renamed as `filename_hetnam[element]` if both conditions are fulfilled. I guessed that I can not use `_` without putting `/`. Have you tried to run the script after changing it and it worked? Cause I've tried and these are the errors I came across. Probably something is wrong with assigning `%letters` but I'm not sure what.. When I try to print `@cols\n` its working fine, but it also prints some formulas that don't fulfill the conditions. And why it says useless use of array in `line 67` when there are no arrays?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to put a slash before an underscore, and as multiple people have been trying to tell you for some time now, this is the immediate reason your code is failing (the slash designates a directory, but there cannot be a directory with the same name as the non-directory file you are trying to rename). *Maybe* you meant to put a backslash, which would merely be harmless, but there is no need for that either (the underscore character just represents itself; it has no special meaning to Perl inside a string).

Comment: @triplee I see, but after changing it doesn't seems to be the only problem. There is a bug in `%letters` as well I think. Have You tried to run it by using this input and script that You have changed? Because when I `print "@cols\n";` it prints all the formulas like it skips conditions..

Comment: I think you are mixing me with someone who actually posted an answer. If you can [edit] your question to explain in more detail what the calculations on the final column are supposed to be doing, I could perhaps give a stab at actually answering.

Comment: @triplee Ok I will edit it now and state what is the problem and what I am expecting.

Answer (score 0):

It could be shell escaping in the system call, or a bug in how you've setup `%letters`.

You might have better success using the built in [rename](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html) or the core module [File::Copy](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html). You could also change your system call to have 3 arguments, one for the process `mv` and one each for the source and destination. But I think you should just use the first two options.

Wait though, I see you're trying to move from `$pdbs` to `$pdbs/_$hetname`. This is going to be tricky, because the file exists, and then you try to move it to a path with its own name in a place were a directory should be? That's going to require multiple steps, like:

```
rename($pdbs, "$pdbs_$hetname");
mkdir($pdbs);
rename("$pdbs_$hetname", "$pdbs/_$hetname");
```

except I hope each `$pdbs` is unique, because otherwise this is going to fail the next time around.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes, I am trying to rename existing files into `existing filename_hetnam` and `@hetnam` are first elements from the lines that start with `HET`. so if both conditions are fulfilled then grep this element from this line and put him into the existing file name by renaming the files. I tried to use `File::Copy module` and to change it into rename context since all pdbs have unique names, but its not working, still receiving some strange errors like : `Useless use of array element in void context at script1 line 67.
Useless use of addition (+) in void context at script1 line 67.`

Comment: @djordje I'm afraid your example code doesn't have 67 lines for me to figure out the meaning of the error.
Perhaps you just want to `rename($pdbs, "$pdbs_$hetname");` and that's all.

Comment: yes, under this line there was nothing it wasn't inside the code thats why I was suprised..

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure of a fix, because you haven't described in detail what your code should do. But the code block for `FORMUL` doesn't make sense, and I think it should be like this

```
if ( $lines[$c] =~ m/^FORMUL\b/ ) {
    my @cols = split ' ', $lines[$c], 4;
    my %letters = ( C => 0, O => 0, N => 0 );

    $letters{$1} = $2 while $cols[-1] =~ m/([A-Z])(\d+)/g;

    next if $letters{C} <= 2
        and $letters{C} + $letters{O} + $letters{N} <= 6;
}
```

Also note that your move operation

```
system ("mv $pdbs $pdbs/_$hetnam")
```

Is asking the system to create a directory with the same name as a file that already exists, which will fail. You can do this in three steps using `tempdir` from `File::Temp`:

```
use File:;Temp 'tempdir';

my $newdir = tempdir;
rename $pdbs, "$newdir/_$hetnam";
rename $newdir, $pdbs;
```

But note that you never set a value for `$hetnam`

Depending on the underlying platform, you may need to replace `rename` with `move` from `File::Copy`

Comment: Thanks. I have put some comments into the code and editted it to be more clearer. I have also used Your approach of renaming files. But there seems to be some bug while assigning `%letters`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `or` in the `next if`?

Comment: @tripleee: That's very possible. I just copied the test from the OP's code. The correctness of the criteria is the least of their problems.

Comment: As outlined in a comment chain elsewhere on this page, the slash was a mistake, and so you don't need to create a temporary directory etc; just call `rename` or `move` with the old and new names as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick stab at reimplementing what you are describing in shell + Awk.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *pdb; do
    if suffixes=$(awk 'BEGIN { suf = "" }
        # If first column is HET and number >= 6, remember this one
        $1 == "HET" && $5 >= 6 { het[$2] = $5 }
        # If first column is FORMUL and this is a HET we remembered ...
        $1 == "FORMUL" && ($3 in het) {
           # If there are parentheses, trim them and anything outside
           sub(/^.*\(/, "", $4);
           sub(/\).*/, "", $NF);
           # Now sum O, C, and N entries, but abort if C <= 2 or missing
           sum = 0
           c = 0
           for(i=4; i<=NF; ++i) {
             if ($i ~ /^[OCN]/) {
               n = 0 + substr($i, 2)
               if ($i ~ /^C/} {
                 if (n <= 2) next;
                 c=1;
               }
               sum += n
             }
           }
           # If we did not see any C, abort this line
           if (!c) next;
           # Now if sum >= 6, add suffix
           if (sum >= 6) suf = suf "_" $3 
        }
        # We are done. Print result if any.
        # Otherwise "exit 1" will cause the calling "if" to fail.
        END { if (suf) { print suf; exit 0 } exit 1 }' "$file")
    then
        mv "$file" "$file$suffixes"
    fi
done
```

This produces the suffix `_RAM_GTR` for your test data and I don't see why `GTR` should not be included if your criteria are correctly articulated.

I will reiterate from comments that one of the errors you had is the slash which you incorrectly added before the underscore in the destination file name. There is no way you can rename a file to a directory name, which is what the slash designates in Unix file names.

Comment: Without comments, this is 18 lines of Awk. It could be condensed a bit still, I suppose. It's comparable to the body of your Perl script, and could probably be rearticulated in Perl just as easily, but after many years with Perl, I still find myself going back to Awk when the problem is simple enough (and now to Python when it isn't).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I missed that, but `GTR` should be added as well. But when I run it on more pdb files, for some of them like `1AA9.pdb` which fulflls both conditions, it doesnt work correctly. I would also like to know what is the bug in my script and get the data with perl so that I can learn from my mistakes. Many thanks!

Comment: This implements the logic you have described. If you have additional requirements, you need to state them -- at the very least, add an example of a case which doesn't work correctly with this code, and explain how it's wrong.

Comment: Anyway, the proper way to fix your script is not to dump it all here and explain piecemeal what it does as people ask for clarifications. Instead, reduce one problem at a time to a single, well-defined piece of code which doesn't do what you want, and post a new question asking for help with just that problem. See also the guidance for creating a [mcve]. (Though chances are you can find an existing question which already has an answer which solves your problem -- search before posting, once you understand exactly what's wrong.)

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: I ran  it on the sample the OP had posted in the question, yes.